# Cannot create SqlSession in myBatis

Tags: java, spring, rest, mybatis, ibatis

I got a spring restful web service. Now I'm gonna integrate mybatis into my project. However, I got problem when I create SqlSession.

From CardValidationController(located from controller package), I call method getCardNoBy from CardValidationService(located from dao package).

I debugged and found that I got stuck in create SqlSession:

```
SqlSession session = sqlSessionFactory.openSession();
```

Any solutions will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you actually NEED to do that? Why not simply create a mapper interface and let the mapper do the whole stuff for you? You can then simple inject the mapper and be done with it...

Comment: Hi, could you give more specific answer, I'm just starting to use myBatis. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is try something very different, using MyBatis-Spring Mapper Interfaces, which allows MyBatis to create simple, thread-safe mapper object that can be injected into your code. This mapper object will effectively allow you to access the mapped queries via methods.

An example would be [here](http://hmkcode.com/mybatis-spring-xml-annotation-mapper/), but the basic idea is to simply create an interface that mirrors the xml mapper definition, for example...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper
PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN"
"http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
<mapper namespace="com.mybatis3.mappers.StudentMapper">
    <resultMap type="Student" id="StudentResult">
        <id property="studId" column="stud_id" />
        <result property="name" column="name" />
        <result property="email" column="email" />
        <result property="dob" column="dob" />
    </resultMap>
    <select id="findAllStudents" resultMap="StudentResult">
        SELECT * FROM STUDENTS
    </select>
    <!-- etc. -->
</mapper>
```

...could be mapped via an interface `com.mybatis3.mappers.StudentMapper`:

```
public interface StudentMapper {
    List<Student> findAllStudents();

    // etc.
}
```

...which would allow you to simple call `StudentMapper.findAllStudents()` instead of calling your query manually.

You can handle mappers via MyBatis-Spring, see [here](https://mybatis.github.io/spring/mappers.html). The most easy way is to scan for them and then inject them as you do with any other Spring managed bean:

```
<mybatis:scan base-package="org.mybatis.spring.sample.mapper" />
```

Comment: I got solution base on the inspire of @Florian Schaetz solution. Thanks you.